# What are the pros/docs of "horizontal" vs "vertical" account structure for managing the AWS cloud service for 1000s of clients

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are developing a custom application, API architecture, related services and processes, based on a LAMP stack and all relevant AWS services: Elastic Beanstalk, EC2, S3, ELB, RDS, API Gateway, Lambda, SNS etc. We would propose to manage the app and all related infrastructure for a flat monthly rate to our client base. We would handle all payment details with Amazon directly for all clients. We are essentially building out a multi-tenant application on AWS. We want to be able to service the AWS infrastructure for potentially 1000s of accounts/clients.

Here is the question: What are the pros/cons of:

**Option A)**  hosting all services in a **single AWS account** using carefully structured IAM roles, users, and permissions, and co-mingling customer data while insuring logical and secure separation of customer data within the account?

**- VS -**

**Option B)** creating a unique AWS for each account each client, and manage each account via a local profile. In this approach, all data is fully segregated, but we have to manage common activities (user management, code deployment, operations) across 100s of discrete accounts. There is a data security advantage, but it is feasible to manage that many accounts?  Any tools or processes for doing it this way? Each company technician would need a login across every account.

The isolation of option B improves security for each client, as any potential security breach would be limited to a single account.  But would code deployments be a nightmare? But what about configuration management?

Is there an account federation service that would help manage option B? Or am I nuts for even considering option B?

Answer (score 1):

Lots to think about, but IMO, in this instance, security trumps all other concerns and that would make me choose option B with the little I know about your setup.

Just think what would happen to your business if the 'master' account was compromised - by a hacker (internal or external) - your clients would be running for the door.

Having lots of accounts to manage is an obstacle, but if treat your infrastructure as code, your code-deployments and everything else can be automated - with 1000s of accounts you will have no choice but to put those systems in place.

Comment: Thank you good points. re "infrastructure as code" What coding options would you consider for option B? Boto? CF?  What language or framework could I consider to automate something like this at scale?